# How to set image as hyperlink in windows form at design time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, hyperlink

I want to set image as hyperlink in windows form at design time. May I know which class should I use, and property I need to set to enable this requirement?

Comment: hyperlink to a folder or file or website?

Comment: hyperlink to another windows form

Comment: Wait... what? Do you mean open a new window, bring up an existing window, or start a new application?

Answer (score 4):

if you want to open an other window (e.g. `Form2`) you can write your code in `Click` event:

```
private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm = new Form2();
    frm.Show();
}
```

And if you want to open a folder in windows explorer, you should do it like so:

```
private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"d:\");
}
```

Comment: even you can use only `explorer`